# A centroid of a triangle based on two known angles

Tags: geometry, triangles, centroid

I have a triangle △ABC and I know two angles of it α = 61° and β = 62° (thus γ = 180-61-62 = 57°).

How do you find a centroid of a triangle based on these fatcs only? Possibly length of one or two sides of the triangle is required for an actual value. In case let us denote them as x (and y if needed).

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the side connecting angles $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is x.

[image]

By sine law, the rest of the sides can be found in terms of x. Let the side opposing the $\alpha$ be f(x).

From the triangle [$x/2, 62^0$, and f(x)], applying cosine law to it to find t (which is also in terms of x).

The centroid is located at one-third of t.

Comment: By which formulation t/3 comes?

Comment: The centroid divides the median in the ratio two to one.